# how to change color of checkbox in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputcheckboxes

I would like change color into green. How to change color because default is blue.

I tried this

```
<ui:inputCheckbox change="{!c.Checked}" />
```

Comment: <ui:inputCheckbox change="{!c.Checked}" />

Comment: how is that supposed to change the color of the checkbox?

Comment: Please take some time to visit [ask] and take the tour to get familiar with the site. Since you do not seem to know much on css, please take some additional time to read [CSS from basic to advanced.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the lightning design system styles by defining your own css classes.

First, you have to add your class to the input:

```
<ui:inputCheckbox class="green-checkbox" value="true" />
```

Then, override the current style with your new class in the css related to your component:

```
.THIS input[type=checkbox]:checked.green-checkbox{
    border-color: rgb(0, 178, 0); /*Choose your color*/
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px #006A00; /*Choose a darker color for the shadow*/
    background-color: rgb(0, 178, 0);
}
```